# Angularjs error while testing typescript ang angular with jasmine and karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test my AngularJS and TypeScript based application with Karma and Jasmine.

My edited `controllerSpecs.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../references.ts" />

describe('ConfigCtrl', () => {
var configCtrl, scope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('typewritingApp'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(($rootScope) => {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    configCtrl = new App.TestCtrl(scope);
}));

it('should be true', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
});
```

My `app.ts`:

```
module App {
import TypewritingCtrl = App.TypewritingCtrl;
import MenuCtrl = App.MenuCtrl;
var typescrip: ng.IModule;
var typewritingapp: ng.IModule = angular.module("typewritingApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap", "LocalStorageModule", "ui.event", "timer"])
    .controller("TestCtrl", ["$scope", TestCtrl])

}
```

My `TestController.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../references.ts" />
module App {
export class TestCtrl {
    constructor($scope: ng.IRootScopeService) {

    }
}
}
```

And the error what karma writes me when I'm trying to run the test:

```
Firefox 41.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.089 secs / 0.119 secs)
29 09 2015 14:58:55.573:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "PROJECT_PATH/Specs/controllerSpecs.js".
Firefox 41.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ConfigCtrl should be true FAILED
    minErr/<@PROJECT_PATH/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
    loadModules/<@PROJECT_PATH/Scripts/angular.js:4411:15
    forEach@PROJECT_PATH/Scripts/angular.js:336:11
    loadModules@PROJECT_PATH/Scripts/angular.js:4372:5
    createInjector@PROJECT_PATH/Scripts/angular.js:4297:11
    workFn@PROJECT_PATH/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:2427:44
    env.executeFiltered@PROJECT_PATH/Specs/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:117:7
    createStartFn/<@PROJECT_PATH/Specs/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171:5
    [2]</Karma/this.loaded@http://localhost:9876/karma.js:190:7
    @http://localhost:9876/context.html:52:5

Firefox 41.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.255 secs / 0.103 secs)
```

If I remove the inject part from my code it runs successfully and the test passes. Can anyone help me what did I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should ask for a service **`$rootScope`** as a local `$scope` generator:

```
// beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(($scope) => {
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(($rootScope) =>
{
    // HERE we do create a $scope from $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    configCtrl = new App.TestCtrl(scope);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RadimKöhler, I've changed the code but still receiving the same error.

Comment: I reproduced your code locally, and it is working for me **as it is**. I just simplified your module `.module("typewritingApp", [])` and implemented empty `TestCtrl`. Test is passing ...

Comment: Then I dont understand. I have added all de js and d.ts files via NuGet Package Manager [this](https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/09/unit-testing-angularjs-with-visual-studio-resharper-and-teamcity/) example also works well. This is how my karma config looks like [link](http://pastebin.com/TUvvGxj2)

Comment: Hard to say, sorry. But in your karma files I do not see app.js or TestController.js (because you do call new TestCtrl)...

Comment: Thanks @RadimKöhler. It was my fault. I didn't add the source files to my config file only the test and script files...

Comment: I am really happy to see, that you started with tests! ;) and it is working. Good luck ...